# Using PHP 5.4 and Freetds

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp, freetds

I keep getting the following message when trying to connect to a ms sql database via PHP

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

I need to do it using FREETDS, I have followed the instructions: http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP

I am using WAMP with php 5.4 the extension is ticked in my extension list in wamp toolbar. One thing I wonder is whether it's something to do with freetds.conf under a standard wamp install where should this go? I have it sitting in the root of c and under bin/php/php5.4.16. The only info I have changed in it is the IP address of the server I want to connect to, is this correct?